# SQL: After joining tables SUM() function returns wrong value

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I am currently working on a database project and have some issues with joining tables. The initial situation is:

four tables:

- tasks t ~ 50000 records
- projects p ~ 1000 records
- workson w ~ 30000 records
- employees e ~ 10000 records

Table w has an attribute called something like "WORKLOAD", unfortunately the result of SUM(w.WORKLOAD) is not the one expected:

```
SELECT
p.NAME,
SUM(w.WORKLOAD) AS "Total Workload",
COUNT(DISTINCT w.ESSN) AS "Total Employees",
COUNT(DISTINCT t.NAME) AS "Finished Tasks" --t.NAME is unique
from p 
JOIN w ON(p.PNUMBER = w.PNO)
JOIN t ON(p.PNUMBER = t.PNO)
WHERE t.END_DATE is NOT NULL
GROUP BY p.PNUMBER, p.NAME
```

After joining these tables, the SUM() function returns a far too big value. I guess that's because the SUM() function counts each w.WORKLOAD value multiple times.

So is there any join operation like inner join that can fix the issue without using subqueries?

 

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: what is the table structure for each table?

Comment: The solution is to aggregate before the `join`.  How you do that in your case is unclear.

Comment: why you have group by p.Number if you show    the result for p.Name ?

Comment: table p: pk=p.pnumber; table w: pk=(e.ssn, p.pnumber); table t: pk=(t.no, p.pnumber);

Answer (score 1):

At issue is a Cartesian product (where rows in one table are being multiplied by the rows in the other tables).  The assumption the following approach is making is that every project has a workload with employees assigned (all of which account for all employees since your query doesn't show the join to the employee table) and tasks.  If this isn't the case, then consider doing outer joins versus the inner join.

The idea is to perform each aggregation in its own derived table based on project number.  We can then join each derived table by project number to obtain meaningful results.

```
SELECT
p.NAME,
w.workload_sum AS "Total Workload",
e.employee_count AS "Total Employees",
t.task_count AS "Finished Tasks"
from p 
JOIN (select pno, sum(workload) as workload_sum
        from w
       group by pno) w ON (w.pno=p.pnumber)
JOIN (select pno, count(distinct w.essn) as employee_count
        from w
       group by pno) e ON (e.pno=p.pnumber)
JOIN (select pno, count(distinct t.name) as task_count
        from t
       group by pno) t ON (t.pno=p.pnumber)
WHERE t.END_DATE is NOT NULL;
```

Comment: why have you got two joins of the w table? You can combine the w and e subqueries into one, like so: `select pno, sum(workload) workload_sum, count(distinct essn) employee_count from w group by pno`

Comment: it was a place holder - as is, employees might not be counted.  The question referred to an employees table - this would be the proper table to join to.