# How to fetch the summation of three columns from three tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

whenever I am fetching the sum from one single table, the output is correct. But whenever I combine three/two separate table at that time the output becomes wrong.
my SQL for a single table is:

```
select users.name, SUM(BC.individual_cost) as breakfast_cost
from breakfast_orders BO, breakfast_costs BC,users
WHERE (BO.date=BC.date) and (BO.user_id=users.id)
GROUP BY(BO.user_id)
```

and here the output is:

```
name                  breakfast_cost
Munna Khandakar       300
Afifa Marowa Anha     180
Fouzia Kabir          50
Atiya Anam Afra Riya  50
```

in the same way,  there are also 2 tables which gives a particular result which is correct. But when ever I join them, the overall result changes.
when I join them like this:

```
select users.name, SUM(BC.individual_cost) as breakfast_cost, SUM(LC.individual_cost) as lunch_cost, SUM(DC.individual_cost) as dinner_cost

from breakfast_orders BO, breakfast_costs BC,users, lunch_orders LO, lunch_costs LC, dinner_orders DOr, dinner_costs DC

WHERE (BO.date=BC.date) and (BO.user_id=users.id) AND (LO.date=LC.date) AND (LO.user_id=users.id) AND (DOr.date=DC.date) AND (DOr.user_id=users.id)

GROUP BY(users.id)
```

then the result becomes

```
name                    breakfast_cost   lunch_cost    dinner _cost
Munna Khandakar         2700             3222          4878
Afifa Marowa Anha       720              552           968
Fouzia Kabir            100              76            242
Atiya Anam Afra Riya    100              76            242
```

here, only by observing the breakfast_cost we can say that the query in not OK. SO if any one help me then I will be very grateful to him.
TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: After joining tables SUM() function returns wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704811/sql-after-joining-tables-sum-function-returns-wrong-value)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: facing difficulty to implement as per table need two join

Answer (score 0):

As @jarlh suggests better to use the explicit joins.

Try the Following

```
select u.name, 
    SUM(BC.individual_cost) as breakfast_cost, 
    SUM(LC.individual_cost) as lunch_cost, 
    SUM(DC.individual_cost) as dinner_cost
from users u 
Left Join breakfast_orders BO on BO.user_id=u.id
Left Join breakfast_costs BC on BO.date=BC.date
Left Join lunch_orders LO on LO.user_id=u.id
Left Join lunch_costs LC on LO.date=LC.date
Left Join dinner_orders DO on DO.user_id=u.id
Left Join dinner_costs DC on DO.date=DC.date
Where not (BO.user_id is null and LO.user_id is null and DO.user_id is null)
```

Comment: only one user's data is coming:
Munna Khandakar    3620   3926   6330

Comment: Comment out the `Where` and see. Please post existing data and expected results, in a way that we can test the query. Also tell what Database is it.